# IF statement in my SiteMaster.cs - determine current file name

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, if-statement, conditional-statements

In my **SiteMaster.cs** file I am using the following query to retrieve data from my database:

`SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("SELECT ID, Title, Name, Keywords, Descr FROM pages WHERE ID=1", conn);`

I would like to do the following:

a) determine the current page & b) use this page to set a pageID variable equal to a certain number.

So if I was on (say) Default.aspx I could do something like...

`// determine file name // if (file name == 'default.aspx') { pageID = 1; }`

Would love some help with this.

Many thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this to get the current aspx filename:

```
string pagePath = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath;
System.IO.FileInfo pageFile = new System.IO.FileInfo(pagePath);
string pageName= pageFile.Name;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String pageName  = Request.FilePath;

//return like that /example.aspx

if (pageName == "/default.aspx") 
{
// your code
}
```

Comment: This will get the virtual path, so it will not work if the file is in a subdirectory. For example it will also return /home/index.aspx

Comment: it is good because /home/index.aspx and /index.aspx consider as different file.

Comment: Terrific, Govind. You have been a brilliant help for me this week. Thank you